# Why do I get this string error in my python 2.7 code

Tags: python

Here's my code, I'm trying to add user input for the IPLIST into the middle of this code. I get invalid syntax each time. What am I missing? I'm not a programmer really, I'm just trying to write simple scripts to automate my tasks:

```
IPs = raw_input('Enter your IPs:') 

print IPs

payload = "{\"name\":\"madefrompostman\",\"description\":\"\",\"context\":\"\",\"status\":-1,\"createdTime\":0,\"modifiedTime\":0,\"groups\":[],\"repository\":{\"id\":233},\"schedule\":{\"start\":\"TZID=America/New_York:20180705T083000\",\"repeatRule\":\"FREQ=TEMPLATE;INTERVAL=1\",\"type\":\"template\"},\"dhcpTracking\":\"true\",\"emailOnLaunch\":\"false\",\"emailOnFinish\":\"false\",\"reports\":[],\"type\":\"policy\",\"policy\":{\"id\":1002387},\"zone\":{\"id\":-1},\"timeoutAction\":\"import\",\"rolloverType\":\"template\",\"scanningVirtualHosts\":\"false\",\"classifyMitigatedAge\":365,\"assets\":[],\"ipList\":\""**IPs**",\"credentials\":[],\"maxScanTime\":\"unlimited\"}"
```

Comment: `**IPs**` is an invalid identifier.

Comment: I'm guessing you want `"very long string" + IPs + "rest of long string"` as opposed to `"..."**IPs**"..."`

Comment: This escaping is overly complicated and unreadable. You could change `payload = "{\"name\":\"madefrompostman\",` to `payload = '{"name":"madefrompostman",'`.

Comment: Just a style note, it might be easier to write out the dictionary literal, and then use a function like [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps).

Comment: That's the thing, the way this payload has to be written, it's written to access an API, it's written so that even if I add the + IP +, it still comes up as a comment.

Comment: Yeah I don't understand the escaping codes either. I got this from the Postman application.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the ideal way to do this but you said you are not a programmer. So, I believe this method will be the easiest for you to work with both now, and in the future.

```
payload = "{\"name\":\"madefrompostman\",\"description\":\"\",\"context\":\"\",\"status\":-1,\"createdTime\":0,\"modifiedTime\":0,\"groups\":[],\"repository\":{\"id\":233},\"schedule\":{\"start\":\"TZID=America/New_York:20180705T083000\",\"repeatRule\":\"FREQ=TEMPLATE;INTERVAL=1\",\"type\":\"template\"},\"dhcpTracking\":\"true\",\"emailOnLaunch\":\"false\",\"emailOnFinish\":\"false\",\"reports\":[],\"type\":\"policy\",\"policy\":{\"id\":1002387},\"zone\":{\"id\":-1},\"timeoutAction\":\"import\",\"rolloverType\":\"template\",\"scanningVirtualHosts\":\"false\",\"classifyMitigatedAge\":365,\"assets\":[],\"ipList\":\""

payload += IPs

payload += ",\"credentials\":[],\"maxScanTime\":\"unlimited\"}"
```

What's happening:

The payload object starts as the beginning of your string. Then your IPs variable is concatenated(attached). Then the end of the string is concatenated.

A shorter and probably better way of writing this is

```
payload = "Beginning of string" + IPs + "end of string."
```